# Trapping SIGINT in a backgrounded process

Tags: bash, signals, background-process

I am trying to understand some sample code describing signal handling in bash.  In Example 32-7 at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html, the writer's comments state that he is capturing a SIGINT, yet the trap is for EXIT.

```
{
     trap "exit" SIGUSR1
     sleep $interval; sleep $interval
     while true; do
         ...
     done; } &         # Start a progress bar as a background process.

pid=$!
trap "echo !; kill -USR1 $pid; wait $pid"  EXIT        # To handle ^C.
```

Why does a trap of EXIT send the correct signal (SIGUSR1) to the backgroud process on a SIGINT (Ctl-C)?

Any help is appreciated explaining why this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EXIT` pseudo-signal is raised both on normal exit and when the script is being interrupted.

Comment: No, it is only when the process calls `exit(2)` itself (either because it reaches the end of script or because of an explicit `exit` instruction).

Comment: Right, the script should have something like `trap 'exit 127' 2 15` to handle this properly.

Comment: Ah.  Got it.  After further testing, I saw that on a keyboard interrupt, the trap of the INT was performed and then the trap of the EXIT occurred.

Answer (score 1):

`EXIT` is a special handler in `trap` for bash, it's not a signal. There is no exit signal. This trap gets executed whenever the bash processes terminates. So, what this does is make sure that if the user kills the bash process, SIGUSR1 is sent to the background process, which also is trapped and then executes 'exit' on that process. That makes sure if you kill the session, the background process doesn't live on forever but also quits (which is probably what the comment is trying to explain).

**edit: I misread this question in my original response**

Comment: You are also misunderstanding the code. A trap for the pseudo-signal `EXIT` is clearly being set on the last line.  This creates an exit handler in Bash. The code serms incomplete, though.

Comment: ... Indeed, the script continues with some long-running commands (see link in question).

Comment: @tripleee You're absolutely right! I didn't even process the last line of code! I will edit my response (the code above is complete)

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, I saw that... I was skimming because it's late here. I guess I shouldn't be attempting to answer questions at this hour and should be attempting to sleep :)